# How to print last array items in console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I print an array for debug purpose with console.log() to a file in my Electron app but it only shows the first items. Is there an option to print the last items instead?

Example:

`console.log(data)`

instead of:

```
{
  threshold: 60,
  currents: [
      15,  157,  145,   20,   18,   18,  120,  122,   58,   67,
      67,   67,  415,  334,  564, 8603, 9492, 9521, 9403, 8992,
    9369, 8991, 9395, 9415, 9327, 9499, 9320, 8876, 8850, 8846,
    ... 81 more items
  ]
}
```

having:

```
{
  threshold: 60,
  currents: [
    ... 81 previous items
    8913, 9409, 9446, 8935, 8869, 9448, 9542, 8875, 9454, 9540,
    8926, 9988, 9390, 9532, 8864, 9503, 9422, 8880, 9428, 9465,
    8896, 9319, 9381, 9404, 8878, 9473, 9491, 8896, 9627, 9522,
    8979, 8866, 9545, 9510, 8872, 9536, 9497, 9556, 9556, 8911,
    9958, 9578, 9243, 8861, 9408, 9418, 8911, 9471, 9447, 8906
  ]
}
```

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` now you will see all of your data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `.reverse()` on the array:

```
console.log({ ...data, currents: data.currents.reverse() })
```